Should I replace this rotten wood in my wall between my kitchen and outside?
We recently bought a house and are trying to do renovations ourselves. This project is the aftermath of some other projects. I am trying to figure out if we should fill/replace this wood between our kitchen walls that appears to of been rotted/chewed away by a mouse. The previous owner had a leak which we believe may of caused some of this rotting. We addressed the leak and now we are addressing the rotting. We believe this is also a place where a mouse has gotten in so we have it stuffed with steel wool for now. The previous owner also went spray foam happy with the crack between the slab and the wall all the way around the perimeter of the kitchen. I am wondering if this is a problem as I have also been reading that in basements you don’t want to fill that gap, but this is our first floor kitchen of a slab home. 

You're talking about the bottom plate?  Is that a concrete wall behind the dark brown stud?

That is some sort of insulation board I think, then some other layers then the siding of the house. The walls are not concrete just the floor
